# STEAMID OPEN ID error

Tags: php, openid

I'm creating a STEAM OPENID for my website but something is giving a error.
I dont know what error is.. Can someone help me...

**ERRORS:**

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\PTgamersCo\steamid.php on line 69

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\PTgamersCo\steamid.php on line 73

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\PTgamersCo\steamid.php on line 76
```

This one is my DB connection

```
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$db = "steam_users";

$sql_steam = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

if (!$sql_steam) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
mysqli_close($sql_steam);
```

This code is to add to the DB.

```
foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player) 
{
    $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid = $player->steamid";
    $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

    //$_SESSION['avatar'] = $player->avatar;

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0) {

        $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO users_steam (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES ('$player->personaname', '$player->steamid', '$player->avatar')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql_steam);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$sql_steam` DOES NOT EQUAL `$db` _Copy/paste must be checked for sanity_

Answer (score 0):

All the `mysqli_*` functions require the first parameter to be the variable returned by your `mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);` call.

Also you need to leave the connection open to be able to use it, so remove the `mysqli_close($db);` in DBCONNECTION script

So amend your DBCONNECTION to this

```
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "steam_users";

$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname );

if (!$db) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
// Dont close the connection, or you wont be able to use it later
//mysqli_close($db);
```

And you other code will have the correct information in the `$db` variable

Comment: Did you include the DBCONNECTION above the code giving the errors

Comment: Show all your code, giving us just bits is dangerous as we dont know what is really going on in your script. also refresh the page as I edited a couple of times, make sure you have all my suggested amendments